# Is there a Regex expression to validate post code?

Tags: c#, regex

The problem is my post code is not being validated so that there can only be four digits and the first digit cannot be `9`.

This is for my new website. I have tried using this:

```
[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$
```

My code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace InspiringMagazines.Models
    {
        public class Customer
        {
                public int customerID { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "GivenName")]
                [MinLength(2), StringLength(20), Required(ErrorMessage = 
    @"The Given Name is required.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"[0-9a-zA-Z' ]{3,20}")]
                public string firstName { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "FamilyName")]
                [MinLength(2), StringLength(20), Required(ErrorMessage = 
    @"The Family Name is required.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"[0-9a-zA-Z' ]{3,20}")]
                public string lastName { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
                public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
                public string emailAddress { get; set; }
                [MinLength(12), StringLength(12), Required(ErrorMessage = 
    @"The Phone Number is required in the format 04xx xxx xxx.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{4}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}        
    [\s.-]\d{3}$")]
                public string mobileNumber { get; set; }
                [MinLength(4), StringLength(4), Required(ErrorMessage =         
    @"The Postal Code is required.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"")]
                public string postalCode { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Expected results are all post codes that start with `9` or aren't 4 digits will display an error message. Actual results are, it currently accepts anything.

Comment: The pattern `^[0-8]\d{3,}$` should work.  This would match any number, 4 digits or more, which does _not_ start with 9.

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern `^[0-8]\d{3}$`

Explanation

`^` - match beginning of a string

`[0-8]` - match digit which isn't `9`

`\d{3}` - match three digits (any)

`$` - match end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AV0an6/1)